# Divisors as a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes

Let $S$ be a scheme and $X$ be a scheme over $S$ corresponding to a smooth projective curve.

Define $X_d := X^d / \mathfrak{S}_d$, where $X^d$ denotes the usual $d$-fold cartesian product of $X$ and $\mathfrak{S}_d$ is the symmetric group on a set of $d$ elements.

Is it true that $X_d$ is a scheme over $S$, as well? If so, how can one show it?

Comment: What does the question have to do with divisors?

Comment: Probably I've not understood the question very well: do you already know that the quotient can be defined as a scheme? And, if this is the case, do you want to show that the resulting scheme is defined over $S$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: The set $X_d$ can be canonically identified with the set of effective divisors over $X$, i.e. formal sums of points of $X$.

Comment: @DanieleA: I don't know how to show that $X_d$ is a scheme, but this should be the case according to the literature.

Comment: @Abramo: Ok, what is your definition of the quotient?

Comment: @DanieleA: What do you mean? The quotient is just $X^d$ but *forgetting about the ordering*

Comment: @Abramo: I think that the definition of quotient that you need here is a different one (even if it implies yours). You can have a look at Exercise 2.14, p. 41 of Qing Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves" for this definition of quotient, and then at Exercise 3.21 p.59, to show that the quotient is a scheme.

Comment: @DanieleA: Sure I will, thanks!

Comment: If $S=\mbox{Spec}(k)$, then the quotient of any projective variety by a finite group acting as a subgroup of automorphisms exists and is a projective variety. This is not difficult to prove: You first show this for affine varieties (this is shown in Shafarevich, for example) and then cover your projective variety by affine open sets that are invariant by your group action. I'm not sure what the situation is like when $S$ is an arbitrary scheme.